# php foreach currpts array in null, if vardump before the foreach is fine, but after (or inside) returns null

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, corrupt

Im using php 7.2 to make a small (simple) project...

So i have:

```
public function setData($data = array())
{

    var_dump($data);

    if (is_array($data) || is_object($data)){

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            $this->{"set".$key}($value);

        }
    }else{
        var_dump($data); 
        exit();
    }

}
```

The first var_dump returns the array fine 
but the second one return NULL 
On the slim aplication it says:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
why?

Comment: dont pass in `setData(['Data' => null])` :/

Comment: If the first var_dump shows you an array, the second one should not be executed at all.

Comment: well that is the problem, i cant find the problem why is slim app saying  ...Invalid argument supplied for foreach()